# Carregar conteúdo de outro arquivo com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, arquivo, load

Gostaria de saber como carrego o código de outro arquivo html ou php usando a função `$(".div").load("html.html");`

O erro aqui seria :

Ele carrega o código perfeitamente, mas tenho um botão nesse HTML, o botão aparece certinho mas ai ele não executa nada, se eu colocar o botão direto sem usar a função `.load()`, ele trabalha certinho, carregando usando o `load()` ele não executa as funções.

Eu achei que o `load` faria a mesma função do `include` do `php` 
alguém pode me explicar?

```
<input class='submit' name='entrar' type='button' value='entrar'>
```

Eu também criei um arquivo `html.php` e dentro dele coloquei um `echo` com o código acima, ele retornou perfeito na tela mas também sem executar a função.

Comment: O php é uma linguagem interpretada do lado do servidor, ou seja, não conheço nenhuma forma de puxar o código fonte do servidor via um código que executa do lado do cliente como é o caso do jQuery. Já o fato do botão não está funcionando corretamente pode ser pelo fato de algum arquivo não ter sido devidamente carregado pela função load(). Mas para poder ajudar seria necessário que você poste arqui o código que faz o load e o que é carregado por este load.

Comment: fabio , a unica coisa que o load carrega e este codigo acima so isso , seria como exemplo , para começar a trabalhar em cima , mas o botao nao funfa

Comment: A página que é carregada ela possui css e js internos? Você olhou se estes elementos foram carregados?

Comment: Pergunta confusa... quando fizer uma pergunta, pense na pessoa que vai ler e não conhece nada do seu sistema e muito menos o que você pretende! Tente colocar informações relevantes de maneira organizada. Você quer carregar um HTML que contém um botão e ao pressioná-lo nada acontece? O que deveria fazer o botão? O que contém o seu HTML?

Comment: Ajax não serve? Abaixo tem um link explicando um pouco mais
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3585/ajax-basico-introducao.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que deve estar ocorrndo, é que você faz o `bind` do evento neste botão no `load` da página, porém ele só é inserido após isso, ficando assim sem ação alguma, o que você tem que fazer, é trazer junto com o ele, o `javascript` que será executado, por exemplo:

**Página principal**

```
$(".div").load("html.html");
```

**html.html**

```
<input class='submit' name='entrar' type='button' value='entrar'>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('input[name="entrar"]').click(function(){
            $('#meu-form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: intendi !! entao a função teria que ser carregada junto com a pagina puxada pelo load certo?? aqui eu deixava a função na pagina principal e o codigo html na pagina secundaria, quando coloquei o codigo do submit junto com o html.html igual o seu exemplo , funcionou perfeito !!! muito obrigado por entender minha pergunta e pelo seu tempo , agradeço a ajuda

Comment: É por ai Jonnys, sugiro que você de uma pesquisada sobre `DOM`. Segue um bom conteúdo para começar: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Answer (score 3):

Use a função [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do jQuery. Ela consegue detectar elementos que são carregados após o processamento da página.

```
$('form').on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(){

    alert('Opá! Bão?');

});
```